# Where does unspecified text 'Komma' in German VoiceOver reading of the 'accessibilityLabel' string 'Feedback' on a view come from?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, accessibility, sample

To be exact: German VoiceOver reads the string value of `"Feedback"` on a view's `accessibilityLabel` as `"Komma Feedback"`. Where does the `"Komma"` part come from???

This is the weirdest bug I've ever seen. Because of the nature of this bug I think one might need to be an Apple dev to know the reason for this bug. Nevertheless, I am interested to hear any possible reasons.

---

Let me go on with the description of the problem. I only experienced this issue with the text "Feedback" until now. You can write what you want after "Feedback", you only need to make sure "Feedback" is at the beginning of the string.

For example:
*"Feedback bla bla bla"* reads *"Komma Feedback bla bla bla"*.
*"bla bla bla Feedback"* however reads *"bla bla bla Feedback"* like expected.

Make sure your VoiceOver language is set to German. English will read the string correctly!

If you want to reproduce the issue, here is a ViewController that you can simply drop into an Xcode project, build and run on a device and experience the issue by yourself with VoiceOver enabled:

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // test it with other UIKit View types

//        let label = UIView()
//        let label = UIButton()
//        let label = UIControl()
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        // optionally set this for non-enabled UIKit types
//        label.isAccessibilityElement = true

        // this reads "Komma Feedback" in German voice over
        label.accessibilityLabel = "Feedback"

        // this reads "Komma Feedback Text" in German voice over
//        label.accessibilityLabel = "Feedback Text"

        // this reads "Mein Feedback" in voice over like expected
//        label.accessibilityLabel = "Mein Feedback"

        // set this to "en" and it just reads "Feedback"
        label.accessibilityLanguage = "de"

        self.view.addSubview(label)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor),
            label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor),
            label.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 10),
            label.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 10)
        ])
    }
}
```

Some stuff in the code is commented out and commented with instructions on how to vary the sample code in order to test other scenarios, too.

I have file a bug on Apple's feedback assistant and posted it on Openradar. You can [check it out here](https://openradar.appspot.com/FB9079388).

Comment: I have amended the text of the question so that it seeks serious answers. The original text seemed to be looking for amusing or creative answers, and that would be off-topic for the site. You never know though, perhaps there are some Apple devs reading...

Comment: Does it ocurrs with another german voice ? If the problem is voice-specific, then you can't do anything except writing to accessibility@apple.com (write in english, not german). There are a lot of voice-specific issues like this in all languages, some of them exist since several years.